# How to make table list inside the Listview?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-tablelayout

I need a table of values inside the listview as a list item. My requirement is like the below image. Please any one explain me how to achieve that. Is it possible to add table layout inside the listview or we can use Listview as a list item of parent listview
[image]

All the values from json. No hard code vales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for being late. I found here searching for a solution for the same problem. Finally I found a nice tutorial.

[This blog](http://android-delight.blogspot.kr/2015/12/tablelayout-like-listview-multi-column.html?m=1)

The key is that you should use `"fill_parent"` for the `LinearLayout` of `row.xml` and using `singleline="true"`, `width="0dp"` with `weight`.

Hope it helped you or forecoming users.

Answer (score 0):

Load the nested list as HTML into TextView

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I need to do some functionality in each item click